# Unable to Configure JRE_HOME after JAVA update

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have already searched for the related post regarding setting your `JRE_HOME` but nothing seem to fix my problem. I have tried all the steps stated but still no changes.

This is what I'm getting as output while executing the 'startTomcat' target:

```
 [exec] The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
 [exec] This environment variable is needed to run this program
 [exec] Result: 1
```

Environmental Variables are as follows:

### User Variables:

- `ANT_HOME`: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-ant-1.9.6
- `CATALINA_HOME`: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
- `JAVA_HOME`: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
- `Path`: 
  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;      C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin

### System Variable:

- `CATALINA_HOME`: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
- `CLASSPATH`: %JAVA_HOME%**

Everything was working fine until I updated Java. I tried reinstalling the JRE and JDK but it still didn't solve my problem. Hope to get clear answers.

Comment: Suggestion: Try adding %JAVA_HOME%/bin to your PATH variable. Also if the error says "JRE_HOME" not defined correctly, did you try to set that variable?

Comment: @vjkumar i already added %JAVA_HOME%/bin. How to set the JRE_HOME variable? same like JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Yes.Just like JAVA_HOME.

Comment: @vjkumar i finally configured it. thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the JAVA_HOME inside eclipse (in ANT run configurations):

1. Right click ANT build file choose Run As > External tools configurations
2. Go to the Environment tab and click new to add JAVA_HOME.
   [refer the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQLwT.png)
3. Click Apply and Run

Please find detailed steps in my site [here](https://java-coding-solutions.blogspot.in/2016/09/exec-neither-javahome-nor-jrehome.html).

Comment: It's always better to explain what the link tells, in case the link goes dead. And advertising your own site like this isn't ok here, at the very least put in a disclaimer that it's your site.